# How to re-prompt a user for input if they enter a string with multiple whitespaces

Tags: java, string, input, whitespace

So i am wondering how I can check a string that has been inputed by the user for multiple spaces, and if it does have multiple spaces between words, i want the user to be re-prompted for input. I am using a do- while loop. here is the format:

```
Scanner scanner01 = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputLast;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a valid LAST name: ");
    inputLast = scanner01.nextLine();
} while()
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove additional spaces instead of annoying the user with it?

Comment: because the input can have at least 1 consecutive whitespace between words. its when the user enters 2 consecutive whitespaces is when there should be an error.

Answer (score 0):

For explanation how to replace multiple spaces with single space read [how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932392/java-how-to-replace-2-or-more-spaces-with-single-space-in-string-and-delete-lead).

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be this (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655810/1546820)):

```
   Scanner scanner01 = new Scanner(System.in);
   String inputLast;
   do {
       System.out.println("Enter a valid LAST name: ");
       inputLast = scanner01.nextLine();
       if(inputLast.length() - inputLast.replaceAll(" ", "").length() <= 1){
           break;
       }
   } while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Sam  ple";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s{2,}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
boolean check = matcher.find();
```