# How to calculate the number of whitespaces in a String

Tags: java, string, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove whitespaces in the beginning of my String by doing the `.trim()` method. But when I try to calculate how many whitespaces I remove it won't work. I have tried making an equation: 
`int spaces = line.length() - line.trim().length()`. But for some reason it always ends up saying the length of the line thats being inputted. Am I missing something here? Or is it some other part of my code?

```
public Squeeze(FileInput inFile, FileOutput outFile)
{
    int spaces = 0;
    String line = "";
    while(inFile.hasMoreLines())
    {
        line = inFile.readLine();
        line = line.trim();
        spaces = line.length() - line.trim().length();
        outFile.println(spaces + line);

    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting an example of the code that does not work.

Comment: If `line.length() - line.trim().length()`, it's because `line.equals(line.trim())`. That's all we know.

Comment: Are you sure your string has leading spaces?

Comment: What type is `inFile`?

Comment: @codeforester Yes I have, for example we put >>      Hello World<< it will trim and output >>Hello World<< but always output the length of the sentence which is 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to count the spaces in a java string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655753/how-to-count-the-spaces-in-a-java-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The OP's code doesn't actually count all whitespaces, only leading ones. For those who want a direct answer to the question:

If you have commons:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(yourText, " ");
```

If you don't:

```
int count = yourText.length() - yourText.replace(" ", "").length();
```

The following solution is based on the OP's code only.

Your problem is in this part:

```
line = line.trim();
// At this point, 'line' has already been trimmed.
spaces = line.length() - line.trim().length();
```

You'll need to either put the trimmed version into some other variable, or move the `line = line.trim()` line until at least *after* you've counted the spaces.

```
public Squeeze(FileInput inFile, FileOutput outFile)
{
int spaces = 0;
String line = "";
String trimmedLine = "";
while(inFile.hasMoreLines())
{
    line = inFile.readLine();
    trimmedLine = line.trim();
    spaces = line.length() - trimmedLine.length();
    outFile.println(Format.left(spaces, 4) + line);

}
outFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Ha! I suspected this was the problem until OP posted his conveniently trimmed-down code.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean their output would always be `0`? How did they get `11`?

Comment: We must still missing some of the code (thus the downvotes) - I took the assumption that the 'spaces' line is probably different, but the underlying issue is probably related to this.